# Class auth.password does not exist in route POST /password/email

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

When I attempt to reset a users password I run into a fatal error once the form filled and posted to /password/email

I'm running Laravel 5.2

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 738:
>   Class auth.password does not exist

All of my views are in place and password_resets exists in the database.

NOTE: this fatal error only occurs when the user fills out the "reset password email form" and hits submit.

Here is the password controller, which is a stock controller.

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

 use Auth;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

 class PasswordController extends Controller
 {
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Password Reset Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
| and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
| explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
|
*/

use ResetsPasswords;

/**
 * Create a new password controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}
 }
```

**Update: Route**

```
Route::controllers([
'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
 ]);
```

Comment: share your routs file please , add route::auth(); to your routes file

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja Updated.

Comment: try to remove that and add Route::auth();  insite a route groupe that have a web middlware (i heard its dropped in recent versions but give it a shot) route::auth is a shortcut for all auth routes (check my answer)

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja Tried that and it threw an error.

Comment: can you put this as answered and tell us what was the probleme (i checked the link you gave me and it works fine now)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it

**routes.php**

```
Route::get  ('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');

// Password reset routes...
   Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
  Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController');
```

Comment: Throws "MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:"

Comment: ill update answer and dont forget to post to the right route

Comment: Throws the same error. I believe it's doing the same thing.

Comment: share the form code , the routes are correct and share full routes file pls (the reset password form that submits the data)

Comment: It's posting to the correct route, just can't figure out why auth isn't being passed when it's in the controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112835/discussion-between-therealjag-and-achraf-khouadja).

Answer (score 0):

Its seems auth is missing, You can simply run this command:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Comment: I have already run that command. It created all the views and such. Login works fine.Just the reset functionality doesn't work.